# Supervised for Unsupervised problem

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering, feature-selection

I am currently working on clustering using R. I have formed clusters using Hclust and PAM. Now, I am trying to find the feature importance for each cluster. As I have features and cluster information, can I Use supervised learning (Caret) to check feature importance for each cluster?

This is how I am planning to do. Sample code is below.

Please advise.

```
library(tidyverse)
head(df_6)
df_7<-df_6%>%filter(df_6$cluster_hclust==1)
fit <- rpart(df_7$cluster_hclust~., data = df_7)
df <- data.frame(imp = fit$variable.importance)
head(df)
df2 <- df %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
  dplyr::rename("variable" = rowname) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(imp) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(variable = forcats::fct_inorder(variable))
ggplot2::ggplot(df2) +
  geom_col(aes(x = variable, y = imp),
           col = "black", show.legend = F) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: It is unclear what df6 is and I have no idea what this line "df_7<-df_6%>%filter(df_6$cluster_hclust==1)" is supposed to do. Generally there is no uniquely well defined concept of variable importance in clustering. Your code will approximate the clustering by a classification tree and then give you the variable importance connected to that tree. Whether this is any good depends on how well the tree will approximate the clustering. It may be OK or go totally wrong.

Comment: I should add that even if the tree approximated the clustering well, there are problems with this approach, because leaving out a variable that has no impact on the tree may well have impact on the clustering.

Comment: Sorry about that, df_6$cluster_hclust==1 refers to the cluster 1 labels. So, when we do clustering what is the best way to find the variables that are most important in each cluster formation? Is there any alternative approach to this? Please advise.

Comment: What we did in this paper https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1467-9876.2012.01066.x (Sec 7.4) is to cluster with a variable left out, and to use the ARI to measure how much the clustering changes. Lower ARI > more change > variable more important.